# How can I detect whether a widget in PyQt5, is a fixed size or not?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working with PyQt5, and I'm looking for a straightforward way to check whether a widget (e.g., QLabel or QPushButton) has a fixed size or not. The direct method isFixedSize() is not universally available.

Could you please share any insights or methods that can efficiently determine if a PyQt5 widget has a fixed size?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class ExampleWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a label with a fixed size
        label_fixed_size = QLabel("label_001")
        label_fixed_size.setFixedSize(100, 30)

        # Create a label with a dynamic size
        label_dynamic_size = QLabel("label_002")

        # Create a button with a fixed size
        button_fixed_size = QPushButton("button_001")
        button_fixed_size.setFixedSize(100, 30)

        # Create a button with a dynamic size
        button_dynamic_size = QPushButton("button_002")

        # Check if a widget has a fixed size
        for widget in [label_fixed_size, label_dynamic_size, button_fixed_size, button_dynamic_size]:
            is_fixed_size_horizontal = widget.sizePolicy().horizontalPolicy() == widget.sizePolicy().Fixed
            is_fixed_size_vertical = widget.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy() == widget.sizePolicy().Fixed
            is_fixed_size = is_fixed_size_horizontal and is_fixed_size_vertical
            print(f"Widget: {widget.text()}, Fixed Size: {is_fixed_size}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**New code**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
import math

class DynamicGridLayoutAdjustments(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label_fixed_size = QLabel("Fixed Size Label")
        label_fixed_size.setFixedSize(100, 30)

        label_dynamic_size = QLabel("Dynamic Size Label")

        button_fixed_size = QPushButton("Fixed Size Button")
        button_fixed_size.setFixedSize(100, 30)

        button_dynamic_size = QPushButton("Dynamic Size Button")

        # Layout with QGridLayout for flexible grid arrangement
        layout = QGridLayout(self)

        # Add widgets to the layout with row and column parameters
        layout.addWidget(label_fixed_size, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(label_dynamic_size, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(button_fixed_size, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(button_dynamic_size, 1, 1)

        # Calculate and set column span and row span based on widget sizes
        col_span_fixed, row_span_fixed = self.calculate_item_span(label_fixed_size)
        layout.addWidget(label_fixed_size, 0, 0, row_span_fixed, col_span_fixed)

        col_span_dynamic, row_span_dynamic = self.calculate_item_span(label_dynamic_size)
        layout.addWidget(label_dynamic_size, 0, 1, row_span_dynamic, col_span_dynamic)

        col_span_button_fixed, row_span_button_fixed = self.calculate_item_span(button_fixed_size)
        layout.addWidget(button_fixed_size, 1, 0, row_span_button_fixed, col_span_button_fixed)

        col_span_button_dynamic, row_span_button_dynamic = self.calculate_item_span(button_dynamic_size)
        layout.addWidget(button_dynamic_size, 1, 1, row_span_button_dynamic, col_span_button_dynamic)

        self.setWindowTitle("Dynamic Grid Layout with Adjustments")

    def calculate_item_span(self, item):
        content_width = item.sizeHint().width()
        label_width = item.width()


        is_fixed_size_horizontal = self.is_fixed_size(item)

        if is_fixed_size_horizontal or item.sizePolicy().horizontalPolicy() == item.sizePolicy().Fixed:
            print("111111 col span")
            col_span_value = math.ceil(label_width / 100)  # Use an example column width
        else:
            print("col_span 222222")
            col_span_value = math.ceil(content_width / 100)  # Use an example column width

        content_height = item.sizeHint().height()
        label_height = item.height()

  
        is_fixed_size_vertical = self.is_fixed_size(item)

        if is_fixed_size_vertical or item.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy() == item.sizePolicy().Fixed:
            print("11111 rwo span")
            row_span_value = math.ceil(label_height / 30)  # Use an example row height
        else:
            print("222222 row span")
            row_span_value = math.ceil(content_height / 30)  # Use an example row height

        return col_span_value, row_span_value

    def is_fixed_size(self, widget):

        return widget.sizePolicy().horizontalPolicy() == widget.sizePolicy().Fixed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DynamicGridLayoutAdjustments()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying achieve?

Comment: I need to dynamically adjust the layout based on whether a widget has a fixed size or not. The current approach using isFixedSize() isn't providing consistent results across different widgets. The ultimate goal is to enhance the responsiveness of the layout by understanding and accommodating various widget sizes. If there's a more effective way to achieve this without solely relying on isFixedSize(), I'd love to explore alternative solutions. What would be the best approach to achieve responsive layout adjustments in PyQt5?"@ekhumoro

Comment: Besides, the documentation clearly explains what `setFixedSize()` does: set the minimum *and* maximum size of a widget, preventing it to grow or shrink. What the size policy then returns (and how it's actually used) is quite a different story, and I tend to agree with ekhumoro: you're probably asking the wrong question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying setFixedSize(). My goal is dynamic layout adjustment based on widget size. While isFixedSize() posed challenges, I'm open to alternatives. Any insights on achieving consistent responsiveness in PyQt5? @musicamante

Comment: I suggest you to provide a proper [mre] of your attempt with some examples showing the obtained result and explaining the expected one. Layout managers are usually quite robust, so having to resort on odd and uncommon behavior is quite peculiar (it often is caused by inaccurate usage and insufficient knowledge of layout mechanics).

Comment: @musicamante, added new MRE

Comment: just i wan to know the widget size, weather its in a fixed size  or not , if it is in a fixed size ,then i get the width and height of the widget as it is. if the widget is not in fixed size, then i try to grow or shrink the widget based on layout size.

Comment: @tckraomuqnt It's still unclear what should be the expected behavior depending on the situation: you're using specific arbitrary values for row heights (30) or column widths (100), but those values seem arbitrary and don't consider other widgets in the related layout cells (which may have different default widths/heights). Besides, setting a row/column span only makes sense if also the starting row sand columns are considered, meaning that each further item would eventually have a different initial grid cell. Right now you're arbitrarily putting them in different cells, which makes spanning »

Comment: @tckraomuqnt » a bit pointless: for instance, using a column span for a widget that is placed in the second column is pointless, because spanning to an otherwise empty column or row has practically no effect unless other widgets occupy other cells in the spanning range. As said, you should provide *examples* of possible case scenarios showing where each widget should be placed depending on the situation. This would eventually help us better understand what you're **actually** trying to achieve.

Comment: @tckraomuqnt All your focus is still on the Y. The X remains obscure, because you haven't provided any realistic context. Abstract examples usually aren't very helpful. Please edit your question and add some screenshots of ***your actual application*** which show the specific problems you are trying to address. If you're using Qt Designer, providing the complete ui file(s) would be even more helpful.